# Setting a Site Wide Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie

Here's what I hope is a quick question...

I am trying to set a cookie that can be used sitewide. I'm creating a lead generation type site. I want users to fill out a form in order to access exclusive information. Once they fill out the form, they have access to the info.

I am dropping a cookie when they user submits the form so that they can just get straight to the content the next time they  visit the site. The form they fill out is in the sidebar of every page on the site. When the user fills out the form on one page, they shouldn't see it on ANY page of the site.

Everything is working, except for the sitewide bit. I think the issue is in this bit of code:

```
function set_cookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure){
if (!expires){expires = new Date()}
document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + 
((expires == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString()) +
((path == null) ? "" : "; path=" + path) +
((domain == null) ? "" : "; domain=" + domain) +
((secure == null) ? "" : "; secure");
}
```

But here's the full code below. THANKS SO MUCH!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
cookie_name="landasp"
expdays=365

// An adaptation of Dorcht's cookie functions.

function set_cookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure){
if (!expires){expires = new Date()}
document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + 
((expires == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString()) +
((path == null) ? "" : "; path=" + path) +
((domain == null) ? "" : "; domain=" + domain) +
((secure == null) ? "" : "; secure");
}

function get_cookie(name) {
var arg = name + "=";
var alen = arg.length; 
var clen = document.cookie.length;
var i = 0; 
while (i < clen) {
var j = i + alen;
if (document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg){
return get_cookie_val(j); 
}
i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1;
if (i == 0) break;
}
return null;
}

function get_cookie_val(offset){
var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf (";", offset);
if (endstr == -1)
endstr = document.cookie.length;
return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
}

function delete_cookie(name,path,domain){
document.cookie = name + "=" +
((path == null) ? "" : "; path=" + path) +
((domain == null) ? "" : "; domain=" + domain) +
"; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-00 00:00:01 GMT";
}

function saving_cookie(){
var expdate = new Date ();
expdate.setTime (expdate.getTime() + (expdays*24*60*60*1000*30)); //set for one month
Data="cooked"

set_cookie(cookie_name,Data,expdate)
}

function get_cookie_data(){
inf=get_cookie(cookie_name)
if(!inf){
document.getElementById("display1").style.display="block"
}
else{
document.getElementById("display2").style.display="block"
}
}

// -->
</script>
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! If you feel an answer answers your question please mark it as answered by clicking the green checkbox.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should specify a site wide path, if the path is not given:

```
((path == null) ? "; path=/" : "; path=" + path) +
```

You can debug the cookies using Firebug, just have a look at the set cookies.

Comment: Thank YOU so much! I've been racking my brain trying to do this!